# Where to find what goes into config.xml in cordova for a plugin (for FileOpener2)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, phonegap-cli

I'm having a problem with a specific plugin in cordova (actually phonegap but same thing-ish right?).  I think i'm missing some fundamental knowledge of how to set up plugins but I can't seem to figure out where this exists.

So.  In my app i have several plugins which i know are working, such as "File", "FileTransfer", etc..

When i installed these plugins i used the command line command "phonegap plugin add [whatever] and was then instructed to add something to the config xml file.  For example for the InAppBrowser plugin i added this:

```
<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
```

Now i want to use the FileOpener2 plugin that i found here: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/

It's not working, and i think it's because i'm missing the entry in my config.xml but i can't seem to figure out what should go here?  Is there some convention that i'm not aware of or some place where you can go to look this up?

Comment: How are you testing the app? are you using the phonegap developer app to test? or are you compiling the actual app and running it?

Comment: So there's two main ways that i'm testing it.  First thing i do is test it in the simulator by running "phongap run ios".  I do this so that i can use safari to see the logs, however there are some issues/features which only work on the phone so for those i run "phonegap serve" and then point the phonegap app on my phone to the IP address of the server.

Comment: when you use serve you run your code on the phonegap developer app, as that app is precompiled, you can only run the plugins that were included by the developer of that app (the core plugins and some 3rd party). So the plugin you are trying to use won't work. Try running with `phonegap run ios --device` that should run your app in your device without using the developer app

Comment: ok so i tried that and nothing happens.  well, almost nothing.  i'm using sublime as my text editor and i can see when i run that command that a bunch of files are swapped around, but neither the emulator nor the app on my phone does anything.  Note, i've tried it with the phone both plugged in and not.

Comment: and none of the messages on the console are helpful?

Comment: phonegap run ios --device
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run ios --device'...
[phonegap] completed 'cordova run ios --device'
vxadmins-mbp:velexo-mobile dallascaley$               <-- sorry i can't format this better in a comment, but this is all i get in the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107563/discussion-between-dallas-caley-and-jcesarmobile).